# Civicrm views in drupal

Tags: drupal, civicrm

i googled a lot about this, went to irc channels but no luck..
I'm using drupal 6 with civicrm 4.2 in a project.
I have a simple view to list civicrm events with the following fields:

CiviCRM Events: Title Training course
CiviCRM Custom: Details: Language Language
CiviCRM Address: Country Country
CiviCRM Custom: Details: Duration Duration

The view works as expected but when i try to expose a filter to the Country field, the operator doesn't show up.. No matter what i do..
I've tried to expose filters in other views and the filters work ok but in this view it won't show up..

I don't if the problem is related only to drupal or only to civicrm, so i hope someone can help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

CiviCRM views integration is currently (Oct 2012) looking for a maintainer, so I am not that suprised that some bits are not 100% functional around the edges.

Asking this question on the [civicrm forum](http://forum.civicrm.org) (when you don't get an answer on IRC) is a good way to go.

The answer will likely be 'you'll need to file an issue preferably with patch'. Sorry I can't be more helpful!

Comment: Thank you for your interest! I'll do that.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick update that the CiviCRM Views integration for v4.5 (current stable version) is much improved and the above is no longer an issue.